# AppEngine full text search cursors broken in dev/unit test environment

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

I've noticed an inconsistency in the behavior of App Engine text search cursors in the devserver or unit test environment vs. production environments.  The dev and unit test environments appear to exhibit a bug for cursors used in combination with sort expressions.  Consider the following unit test code:

```
@Test
public void testQueryCursor( ) throws Exception
{
    testQueryCursor("id_%02d"); // works
    testQueryCursor("id_%d"); // fails
}

private void testQueryCursor( final String idFmt ) throws Exception
{
    final int TEST_COUNT = 12;
    final Index index =
            SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService().getIndex(IndexSpec.newBuilder().setName("MY_TEST_IDX").build());

    final List<String> docIds = new ArrayList<String>(TEST_COUNT);
    try {
        // populate some test data into an index
        for (int i = 0; i < TEST_COUNT; i++) {
            final String docId = String.format(idFmt, i);
            final Document.Builder builder = Document.newBuilder().setId(docId);
            builder.addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("some_field").setText("str1 " + docId)); // include varied docId in field for sorting
            index.put(builder.build());
            docIds.add(docId);
        }

        // for comparison to sorted search results
        Collections.sort(docIds);

        // define query options
        final QueryOptions.Builder optionsBuilder =
                QueryOptions
                        .newBuilder()
                        .setReturningIdsOnly(true)
                        .setLimit(10)
                        .setSortOptions(
                                SortOptions
                                        .newBuilder()
                                        .setLimit(20)
                                        .addSortExpression(
                                                SortExpression.newBuilder().setExpression("some_field")
                                                        .setDirection(SortDirection.ASCENDING).setDefaultValue("")));

        // see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/results#Java_Using_cursors
        // create an initial per-query cursor
        Cursor cursor = Cursor.newBuilder().build();
        final Iterator<String> idIter = docIds.iterator();
        int batchIdx = 0;
        do {
            // build options and query
            final QueryOptions options = optionsBuilder.setCursor(cursor).build();
            final Query query = Query.newBuilder().setOptions(options).build("some_field : str1");

            // search at least once
            final Results<ScoredDocument> results = index.search(query);
            int batchCount = 0;
            for (final ScoredDocument match : results) {
                batchCount++;
                assertTrue(idIter.hasNext());
                assertEquals(idIter.next(), match.getId());
                System.out.println("Document " + match.getId() + " matched.");
            }
            System.out.println("Read " + batchCount + " results from batch " + ++batchIdx);
            cursor = results.getCursor();
        } while (cursor != null);
    } finally {
        index.delete(docIds);
    }
}
```

If the `assertEquals(idIter.next(), match.getId());` line is commented out the full output of the previously failing call the `testQueryCursor("id_%d")` can be observed and we see that the proper ordering of results appears to be ignored.  What's more, the last search performed on the cursor repeats the last two elements retrieved from the previous search call.  Since these two elements SHOULD BE the last two returned from the search perhaps this behavior is simply an artifact of the flaw which causes the improper sort.

This code can be easily run as a unit test as shown here or run from a JSP on the devserver and the behavior is consistent.  When run as a JSP on a production instance of App Engine the behavior differs in that the search returns the correctly ordered results in all cases.  It would be nice if the devserver environment and unit test tools were fixed to provide correct behavior consistent with production.

Comment: At https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=2&q=component=FullTextSearch&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log I see several open issues wrt fulltextsearch running locally (in the SDK as opposed to prod) but don't see your specific one as having been raised yet -- perhaps open a new defect about it?

Comment: Thank you Alex, I just filed my first bug with Google:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11818